# Pair wise function repeated N times per row

Tags: r, leaflet

I have a dataframe which contains 8 unique lat long coordinates pairs per row which I wish to plot. How can I pass each pair of lat longs to the addPolygons function within Leaflet to plot the data row by row?

Once at the end of the row the function should 'stop' and then 'start' again on the next row. The reason I would like to 'stop' the function is to prevent a polygon being drawn from the polygon data of row N to row N+1. Currently this is happening to my polygons when I plot them, it is drawing a polygon to the next site which is not desired.

Below is the code I am using to generate these plots courtesy of @HubertL

```
m <- as.matrix(t(siteCoor), byrow=T)
dim(m) <- c(2,length(m)/2)
map <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
       addPolygons(lng=m[1,],lat=m[2,])
```

[image: Polygon]

Sample data is below and at the following [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzkBEqPfozOOUmpDLTd6Q0N5Tm8/view?usp=sharing) in dput() format

```
> head(siteCoor, n = 12L)
   Longitude Latitude         1        2         3        4         5        6         7        8         9       10        11       12        13
1  -8.609117 52.69373 -8.609505 52.71620 -8.602948 52.71588 -8.596586 52.71487 -8.590621 52.71319 -8.585241 52.71089 -8.580617 52.70805 -8.576895
2  -8.609117 52.69373 -8.590303 52.67439 -8.596234 52.67268 -8.602573 52.67162 -8.609117 52.67127 -8.615662 52.67162 -8.622000 52.67268 -8.627931
3  -8.609117 52.69373 -8.644000 52.70119 -8.641276 52.70483 -8.637535 52.70811 -8.632894 52.71094 -8.627501 52.71323 -8.621527 52.71490 -8.615159
4  -8.609117 52.69373 -8.609458 52.71350 -8.603688 52.71323 -8.598090 52.71233 -8.592841 52.71085 -8.588107 52.70883 -8.584038 52.70633 -8.580762
5  -8.609117 52.69373 -8.592560 52.67671 -8.597780 52.67520 -8.603358 52.67428 -8.609117 52.67396 -8.614877 52.67428 -8.620454 52.67520 -8.625674
6  -8.609117 52.69373 -8.639813 52.70030 -8.637416 52.70349 -8.634123 52.70639 -8.630040 52.70888 -8.625294 52.71089 -8.620037 52.71236 -8.614434
7  -8.609117 52.69373 -8.609411 52.71081 -8.604429 52.71057 -8.599594 52.70980 -8.595061 52.70852 -8.590973 52.70677 -8.587459 52.70461 -8.584630
8  -8.609117 52.69373 -8.594817 52.67904 -8.599325 52.67773 -8.604143 52.67693 -8.609117 52.67666 -8.614092 52.67693 -8.618909 52.67773 -8.623417
9  -8.609117 52.69373 -8.635627 52.69940 -8.633556 52.70216 -8.630713 52.70466 -8.627186 52.70681 -8.623088 52.70855 -8.618547 52.70982 -8.613709
10 -8.609117 52.69373 -8.611750 52.72064 -8.603143 52.72045 -8.594761 52.71924 -8.586920 52.71708 -8.579916 52.71403 -8.574012 52.71023 -8.569431
11 -8.609117 52.69373 -8.584672 52.67124 -8.592290 52.66879 -8.600542 52.66728 -8.609117 52.66677 -8.617692 52.66728 -8.625944 52.66879 -8.633562
12 -8.609117 52.69373 -8.651647 52.70143 -8.648402 52.70627 -8.643678 52.71064 -8.637652 52.71438 -8.630550 52.71734 -8.622640 52.71941 -8.614220
         14 Longitude Latitude
1  52.70476 -8.609117 52.69373
2  52.67439 -8.609117 52.69373
3  52.71590 -8.609117 52.69373
4  52.70343 -8.609117 52.69373
5  52.67671 -8.609117 52.69373
6  52.71324 -8.609117 52.69373
7  52.70211 -8.609117 52.69373
8  52.67904 -8.609117 52.69373
9  52.71058 -8.609117 52.69373
10 52.70580 -8.609117 52.69373
11 52.67124 -8.609117 52.69373
12 52.72051 -8.609117 52.69373
```

Comment: Nice looking map. Please use `dput()` for sharing data in the `r` tag. Hover your pointer over the `r` tag for more info.

Comment: Thanks, link added to dput output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to use `sp::SpatialPolygons()`.

```
library(sp); library(dplyr)

mat <- as.matrix(sample_data)
```

If you want to completely separate each polygon that consist of one row, it might be a good idea to make class `Polygons` per row (`leaflet()` treats class `Polygons` like independent object).

```
sp <- lapply(1:nrow(mat), function(x) matrix(mat[x,], byrow=T, ncol=2)) %>% 
  sapply(Polygon) %>%          # convert each row into list(matrices) and make list(Polygon)
  mapply(function(x, y) Polygons(list(x), ID = formatC(y, digits=3, flag="000")), x = ., y = 1:length(.)) %>% 
  SpatialPolygons()

sp %>% leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons()
```

**Another approach**

When `c(lng, lat)` is `c(NA, NA)`, polygon breaks at the point.

```
dat <- cbind(sample_data,NA, NA)

m <- as.matrix(t(dat), byrow=T)
dim(m) <- c(2,length(m)/2)
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(lng=m[1,],lat=m[2,])
```

[image]

You just want to delete polygon between sites, just make one class `Polygons` having some class `Polygon`. (but if you make class `Polygons` par site, it works in some situations).

```
mat2 <- rbind(mat[1:6,], mat[1:6,] + 0.04)  # example data

sp2 <- lapply(1:nrow(mat2), function(x) matrix(mat2[x,], byrow=T, ncol=2)) %>% 
  sapply(Polygon) %>% Polygons(ID = "a") %>% list() %>% SpatialPolygons()

sp2 %>% leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons()
```

[image]

**[Addition 1: scale]**
When you do size (scale) changes, it is needed to temporarily move all points  to change the criterion point into `c(0,0)`.

```
 ## basic idea
exam <- matrix(c(1:4, 16:19), ncol=2)   # the criterion point (the point you don't want to change) is c(1,16)
exam_scaled <- ( exam - exam[rep(1,nrow(exam)),] ) * 0.8  + exam[rep(1,nrow(exam)),]
                        # move                   size change      turn back
 ## example data
mat3 <- as.matrix(sample_data[11:12,])

s <- 0.8     # scale

sp3 <- lapply(1:nrow(mat3), function(x) matrix(mat3[x,], byrow=T, ncol=2)) %>% 
  lapply(function(x) (x - x[rep(1, nrow(x)),]) * s + x[rep(1, nrow(x)),]) %>%    # scale change
  sapply(Polygon) %>%
  mapply(function(x, y) Polygons(list(x), ID = formatCy, digits=3, flag="000")), x = ., y = as.numeric(rownames(mat3))) %>% 
  SpatialPolygons()

sp[10:12] %>% leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons() %>% 
  addPolygons(data = sp3, col = "red")   # 0.8 scale
```

[image]

**[Addition 2: color]**
I think it would be a good idea to use `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` (it isn't essential but this methods can keep all information in one object).

```
 # example data (change positions par 3 polygons)
mat4 <- as.matrix(sample_data) + matrix(c(rep(0, 54), rep(rep(c(0.08, 0), 9), 3), 
  rep(rep(c(0, -0.06), 9), 3), rep(rep(c(0.08, -0.06), 9), 3)), byrow = T, nrow = 12)

sp4 <- lapply(1:nrow(mat4), function(x) matrix(mat4[x,], byrow=T, ncol=2)) %>%  # the same as above code without data
  sapply(Polygon) %>% 
  mapply(function(x, y) Polygons(list(x), ID = formatC(y, digits=3, flag="000")), x = ., y = 1:length(.)) %>% 
  SpatialPolygons()

df <- data.frame(col = rep(c("red", "green", "blue", "cyan"), each = 3),  # for directl definition
                 factor = as.factor(rep(1:4, each = 3)), numeric = 1:12)  # for fanctional approach

rownames(df) <- getSpPPolygonsIDSlots(sp4)           # change rownames into sp4's ID
spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sp4, data = df)     # make SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
spdf@data    # data

 # for functional approach
col_fac <- colorFactor(c("red", "green3", "blue", "cyan"), domain = NULL)
col_num <- colorNumeric(colorRamp(c("white", "red")), domain = NULL)

spdf %>% leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons(color = spdf@data$col)
         # equivalent to addPolygons(color = rep(c("red", "green", "blue", "cyan"), each = 3))
spdf %>% leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons(color = col_fac(spdf@data$factor))
    # The slight color difference from the upper code might come from the difference of color name definition between leaflet and R
spdf %>% leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons(color = col_num(spdf@data$numeric))

 # Note: When you use some parts of SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, you need to transform 
 #       it into SpatialPolygons, such as SpatialPolygons(spdf@polygons)[1:4] %>% ...
```

[image][image]

Comment: thanks for taking the time to run through problem and showing me how to work through this, many thanks again. By any chance could you suggest a way to modify the size of the segments when looking at a city center location where there could be 20+ cells, right now there is too much overlap from neighbouring cells and it makes the map too cluttered. I could reduce the size of the cell polygon computation but I was wondering if there's a smarter, more dynamic way to achieve scalable polygons? Many thanks again for your help.

Comment: Once again thank you very much, I have a question about the additional comments you added above. In the second last line of the [Addition] section should SP[10:12] be SP3?

Comment: @PigWolf; No, `sp` is the object made in 2nd code block. `sp` has 12 class `Polygons` and I pulled 10-12th to compare (`sp3` is made from 11 & 12 rows, so no size change version of `sp3` is `sp[11:12]`. I didn’t mean anything by not using `sp[11:12]` but `sp[10:12]`.

Comment: thanks you so much once again. I don't fully understand the code line for line but I managed to get my image to scale by adjusting the S value all the way down to 0.05 which works perfectly in the city areas. I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: Since I am plotting a matrix of lat long coordinates with no categorial variables in it, how can I specify the colour for the 4 cell ranges i.e 3088==red, 10564==blue, 10589==green and 10613==orange? Do I need to convert sp3 back to a DF and merge some of the categorical variables such as the value above and assign the colour based on these and add another addPolygons with data = sp3 and colour = someDF$cellrange?

Comment: @PigWolf; You needn't add color information into original DF (of course, you need to define it in some ways). I edited. (and I change the Id code)

Answer (score 1):

Hadley's [purrr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrr/index.html) gives you the machinery for this sort of thing (simultaneous mapping over multiple arrays), although the previous answer was probably more on-point for your exact application. Specifically, you should use the `map2` function from said package.